# Bash: Change to Directory with Space

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have no idea what could be wrong here, I have just installed Ubuntu and I am trying to run a program called Exercise2.cpp. Exercise2.cpp is inside a folder called C++ Development in the Documents directory.

I can get as far as the Documents directroy, however when I try to change in to C++ Development it says " bash:cd: C++: No such file or directory"

What does this mean, I have been trying different things, like adding C++ Development in a quote but it still does not work.?

Comment: try `cd C++\ Development`

Comment: `cd 'C++ Development'` - single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Escape the spaces with a backslash.

```
cd C++\ Development
```

In general, though, it's good practice to avoid using spaces in file and directory names. Avoiding spaces makes it much easier to use the simple UNIX tools to do sophisticated stuff with your data.